# Enviar clique do mouse

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber como enviar clique do mouse na tela passando as coordenadas de posição do clique (x,y) por parâmetro em c#.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055211/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-click

Comment: Neste link só tem como obter(get) a posição, gostaria de setar a posição... Movimentar o mouse.

Comment: Está utilizando Windows Forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se estiver utilizando Windows Forms, para movimentar o cursor utilize a classe [Cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.cursor(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - positionX, Cursor.Position.Y - positionY);
        Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
```

Para movimentar e clicar, será necessário que você importe a biblioteca do Windows. Segue exemplo abaixo:

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;


    private void mouseClick(int x, int y)
    {
        SetCursorPos(x, y);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
    }
```

[Referencias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272681/how-can-i-simulate-a-mouse-click-at-a-certain-position-on-the-screen)

Comment: Este método altera a posição do cursor na tela e envia o clique do mouse naquela posição?

Comment: Editei a resposta, abraço.